# I am using ExoPlayer 2.16.1 and I cannot import DefaultHttpDataSource

Tags: java, android-studio, stream, video-streaming, exoplayer

I'm getting an error like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no TLS versions for cleartext connections" in my project and I need to use "DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory" to fix it, but I can't import it.

My ExoPlayer version:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.16.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.16.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.16.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.16.1'
```

Where I use "DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory":

```java
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                Util.getUserAgent(context, "your-application-name"),
                null /* listener */,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                true /* allowCrossProtocolRedirects */
        );
```

Permissions:

```xml
        <uses-permission tools:node="merge" android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Application tag:

```
<application
    .
    .
    .
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    .
    .
    .>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was removed in `2.16.0`.
Use `DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory` instead.